# In eclipse how to add existing maven project as web project

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

i am trying to run maven project as dynamic web projects.

I have my maven project in my eclipse. i want to run project on localhost:8080/abc like this.

Please suggest me the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I dont know if this is what you are looking for, but if you just want to run your Maven Web project easily, you can use the [jetty-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/) to run it.

The configuration would be:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.3.v20120416</version>
    <configuration>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/abc</contextPath>
        </webAppConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your maven project should be a web project (`<packaging>` should be `war` for instance).

You should have `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers`.

You should configure a server in your Eclipse - say tomcat, jetty, etc.

Install [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) Eclipse plugin as well as [m2e-wtp](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP) support plugin.

Import maven project to Eclipse.  After it build you should be able to choose "Run as server..." option and specify the server you have configured.